# can someone explain me why when a "string" is used with the "%d" fromat specifier it gives strange output

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers, format-string

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  printf("%d", "A"); // Can i know what the output from "printf" even means why the output is so strange

} // this outputs: "4214884" in my compiler
```

As you see the output is so strange and can anyone of you explain this to me. Is this undefined behavior? Is this behavior described anywhere in the [C standard](http://www.port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html) so I can read about it

Comment: `%d` is use for `int` values. So `"A"` is not a correct type. If you want to use strings you should replace by `%s`. I guess the value `4214884` is the byte representation for a char array with an `A` character on the first position.

Comment: You must be aware that this can also affect all other parameters that you want to print. Especially if the size of an `int` is different than the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this **is** [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). `%d` expects the argument to be an integer, here what you pass is the address of the first element of a string literal, which is a pointer type.

As per `C11`, [chapter 7.21.6.1/P9](http://www.port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9)

> *[...]If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*

That said, for a hosted environment, `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: Just to complete the answer and explain why it is undefine : The `%d` makes the `printf` function interpret the input as an integer.
In the memory, an int or a char are just the same : bytes. If you try to print something of type A, in type B, it will show the equivalent of these bytes, interpreted as type B... And show you black magic.

Comment: @totok maybe that's most practical, only thing is that, it's **not** guaranteed behaviour in general. We need to know the compiler and environment details to validate the speculation, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print a character with `%d` specifier, put single quotes around the character not double-quotes.

> `printf("%d", 'A');`

This will print 65, the ASCII value of A.

If you put anything inside double-quote that will be interpreted as a `string literal`. So, it has two characters(in your case), one is `'A'` and the second is `'\0'` character and you are printing it with `%d` specifier which will completely yield `undefined behaviour`. This will show different results on different compilers and IDEs.

If you want to print `"A"`, I mean using double-quotes, use `%s` identifier instead.